# Octave, barplot, only one row

Tags: bar-chart, octave

I need to plot a bar graph in Octave. The following code:

```
clf;

data = rand(4, 5);

h1 = bar(data(1, :), "stacked");
l1 = legend("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5");
legend(l1, "location", "northeastoutside");

figure
h4 = bar(data, "stacked");
l4 = legend("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5");
legend(l4, "location", "northeastoutside");
```

does it. The second plot produces exactly what I need:
[image]

The first one, however, does not work as I would assume it would:

[image]

Is there any way to have a one-row bar plot that produces a graph with only one column in the style of the first plot?

Thanks in advance.

Rodrigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an elegant solution, but it can work in most of the cases.

The idea is to plot an additional bar (in x=2), and then hide it changing the
limits of the x axis (let's say [0.05, 1.95]):

```
M=zeros(2,4);
M(1,:)=rand(1,4);

bar(M, "stacked");
xlim([0.05 1.95]);

l1 = legend("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5");
legend(l1, "location", "northeastoutside");
```